# Lay website out with HTML then style with CSS after?

Tags: html, css

I was just curious if it was better to lay out your website/webpages by using HTML first and then style it with CSS afterwards or is it best to style it as you're working on it?

Comment: Both approaches exist and it's down to what you're more comfortable with. Me, I style as I go. It gives me a feel for how the site and layout are progressing. I can't really track this if all I see is stacked elements in black and white.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. HTML and CSS work hand in hand so I would suggest you do both at the same time.

Comment: I think it depends on your page, but usually without CSS you won't be able to write what you want in HTML duo to crucial features of CSS like "width", "float" etc. So my opinion is that writing them both together will be better

Comment: I usually like to do both at the same time, and modify my HTML/CSS accordingly. It shows me how much progress I've made, and it motivates me. But it might not be same for everyone, though.

Answer (score 2):

The current "best-practice" methodologies for web development are "**Progressive Enhancement**" (http://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement) and "**Separation of Concerns**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript). While HTML *can* provide layout for a page, that should be avoided since the elements used to do so would not be semantically correct and the page may actually take longer to render.

- HTML is for the content and semantics of a web page (not aesthetics).
- CSS is for presentation and layout.
- JavaScript is for behavior.

By using each language for its intended purpose, you are following the Separation of Concerns principle. This concept makes a page much easier to debug and scale over time.

By starting with just HTML and content and then adding CSS after that and then adding JavaScript after that, you are following the Progressive Enhancement principle. Following this concept ensures a baseline look, feel and behavior that you know will work with your intended audience.

It's also important to recognize that in today's world there isn't going to be just one layout that works for your pages. That's why a third development methodology, called "**Responsive Web Design**" (http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) is the current best-practice. Given that there isn't just one layout that you'll need, it's more reason to do the HTML first, the CSS second and the JavaScript last.